# Centering Xcircuit Figure

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

Hi I am using a program called xcircuit to make circuit diagrams and I cant seem to get the figure centered. I have tried `\begin{center}`, `\centering`. I have tried messing with `\flushleft` but it needs to be flushleft for the words to line up in the figure (see attached image) These commands work when i use `\includegraphics.` I know its not a bounding box problem.  Thanks for your help here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
 \input{hvdc}
 \caption{CIGR\'E Idealized Rectifier Station}
 \label{fig:hvdc}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
 \input{hvdc}
 \end{center}
 \caption{CIGR\'E Idealized Rectifier Station}
 \label{fig:hvdc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code generated by Xcircuit for hvdc.tex

```
\def\putbox#1#2#3{\makebox[0in][l]{\makebox[#1][l]{}\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{\raisebox{#2}[0in][0in]{#3}}}}
\def\rightbox#1{\makebox[0in][r]{#1}}
\def\centbox#1{\makebox[0in]{#1}}
\def\topbox#1{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}
\def\midbox#1{\raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}
\begin{flushleft}
\epsfig{file=C:/Users/kasun/Desktop/center_pic/hvdc.eps}\\
% translate x=1222 y=-12 scale 0.38
\putbox{2.46in}{1.27in}{$1000 kV$}%
\putbox{0.42in}{1.08in}{$345 kV$}%
\putbox{0.42in}{0.91in}{$50 Hz$}%
\putbox{1.00in}{2.08in}{$345 kV:422 kV$}%
\putbox{0.25in}{0.49in}{$P_{ac}$}%
\putbox{1.17in}{1.24in}{$P_{6pulse}$}%
\putbox{1.17in}{0.24in}{$P_{6pulse}$}%
\putbox{2.34in}{0.08in}{$P_{dc}$}%
\end{flushleft}
```

[image]

Comment: comment out `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}` lines in `hvdc.tex` then you may get the figure centered. you might be better off with [circuitikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz?sort=votes&pageSize=50) package.

Comment: Still a problem? I cannot test, as I don't have the EPS-files, but does it work if you add `\usepackage{varwidth}`, and replace `\begin{flushleft}`/`\end{flushleft}` with `\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}`/`\end{varwidth}`?

Answer (score 1):

made comment into answer

comment out `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}` lines in`hvdc.tex` then you may get the figure centered. you might be better off with [circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz?sort=votes&pageSize=50) package. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but if I don't use flush left the text wont align properly with the picture

Comment: @Kasun In that case wrap the `text` only in `flushleft` environment and leave the figure separately. BTW `epsfig` is a very old package it's superseded by [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and avoid `xcircuit` if possible as it generates outdated latex code. Use `circuitikz` package